# Match data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I've 4 tables, :

**login** with columns userid, name, pass, email
**phyinfo** with columns userid, height, skincolor, ethnicity, gender, bodytype
**loc** with columns userid, country, state, city
and
**skills** with columns userid, skillslists which has index of skill values (comma separated)

now i want to search user by all (eg: *height=5'21" + gender=male + country=india + skills=design*)

I dont know how to make this mixed query which will return the user id(s) of the matched criteria. please help

This is the query i have tried so far :

```
SELECT userid 
 FROM phyinfo 
 WHERE height='5\'21"' AND gender='male' 
 UNION 
  SELECT userid 
  FROM loc 
  WHERE country='india' 
  UNION 
   SELECT userid 
   FROM skills 
   WHERE FIND_IN_SET(8 , skillslists)
```

Comment: Did you try anything before posting the question??

Comment: i tried join and union but not getting the result

Comment: Then please _post_ that join you tried here so that we can figure out the problem.

Comment: @user3409146 : show whatever you tried *in code* .... *not in theory*  :)!!

Comment: SELECT `userid` FROM phyinfo WHERE `height`='5\'21"' AND `gender`='male' UNION SELECT `userid` FROM `loc` WHERE `country`='india' UNION SELECT `userid` FROM `skills` WHERE FIND_IN_SET(8 , skillslists)

Comment: @user3409146: How do you store height in `phyinfo` table? Could you show some samples? If it is like 5'21" exactly, you can use my answer.

Comment: actually its in cms when getting res i convert it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT L.userid,L.name,L.pass,L.email
FROM login L INNER JOIN
   phyinfo P on L.userid=P.userid INNER JOIN
   loc on L.userid=loc.userid INNER JOIN
   skills S on S.userid=L.userid
WHERE P.height='5''21"' AND P.gender='male' AND loc.country='india' AND S.skillslists LIKE '%design%'
```

Comment: @user3409146: It is a pleasure, my friend.